# New DataFrame column from contatenation

Tags: r, azure, apache-spark, sparkr

What I'm trying to do in SparkR (R on Azure Databricks) is to add a new column made from concatenation of two other existing columns:

```
fitted_new <- withColumn( fitted, 'OBS',  paste( fitted$Date, fitted$Quarter, sep = ''))
```

This results with an error:

> Error in as.character.default(new("Column", jc = )) : Error in as.character.default(new("Column", jc = )) :  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector

Looks like the PASTE function can't be inserted as a column... Is there any way of casting it? Any other approach?

If PASTE is not used in there, but something like `fitted$Quarter * 3` - all works fine.

Comment: try using spark `concat`, e.g. `withColumn( fitted, 'OBS',  concat( fitted$Date, fitted$Quarter))`

Answer (score 0):

This worked as suggested by @mck in comments:

```
fitted_new <- withColumn( fitted, 'OBS',  concat( fitted$Date, fitted$Quarter))
```